# De-authorize a Facebook app using the new OpenGraph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code to de-authorize my FB application for currently logged in user:

```
FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' });
```

It's using the deprecated REST API. How do I do the same using the OpenGraph API with FB.api method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API SDK revoke access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete", function(response){});
```

Answer (score 1):

In graph API you can issue HTTP DELETE request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/_UID_/permissions
```

this should deauthorize the app