# Facebook API SDK revoke access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I allow a user to revoke access to my application using their API service, SDK. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

Looking at the documentation I can't find anything about revoking the access.

Comment: For further reading I found this useful https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-logout/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in the graph API for the user object you can issue an HTTP DELETE request to /PROFILE_ID/permissions to revoke authorization for an app.

from the official documentation ([developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)):

> You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended
>   permissions on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to
>   PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token for that app.
>
> Parameter  Description     Type    Required permission     The permission you
>   wish to revoke. If you don't specify a permission then this will
>   de-authorize the application completely.  string   no You get the
>   following result.
>
> Description    Type True if the delete succeeded and error
>   otherwise.    boolean

Comment: What's nice is you can do this server or client side.  Whatever way you want.

Comment: The correct link to the API is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#revokelogin

Answer (score 32):

For the ***FB JavaScript SDK***:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', 'delete', function(response) {
    console.log(response); // true
});
```

Comment: API link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#revokelogin

Comment: what about PHP SDK ?

Comment: The net effect is you are logged out of an App but not out of facebook; Your status with respect to the App then becomes 'not_authorized'. This is not at all clear, from the FB DOCO (someone correct me if i am wrong).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who would find this helpful, I was losing sleep and wrecking my brain for days trying to get this to work;

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE', function(response) {
    if (response == true) {
        window.top.location = 'logout-facebook.php';
    } else {
        alert('Error revoking app');
    }
});
```

I finally got this to work when I observed that the "response" being returned was not a boolean but a JSON object.

The JSON object being returned was either;

```
{
    success: "true"
}
```

OR

```
{
    success: "false"
}
```

Following that, the correct code was;

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE', function(response) {
    if (response.success == true) {
        window.top.location = 'logout-facebook.php';
    } else {
        alert('Error revoking app');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

With PHP SDK V 5

```
$DeletePermsUser = $fb->delete('/{user-id}/permissions/',[],$access_token);
```