# How do you remove the facebook provider using omniauth-facebook in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm able to attach an account to my users using the normal `omniauth-facebook` methods.  How do I remove the app from the user?  Does `omniauth-facebook` have the functionality to do this?  I know for example Pinterest is able to link and unlink facebook from their users.  When unlinking is done, the Pinterest app disappears from the facebook user's application list.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @JakeSmith see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook Graph API to revoke access to your application.

You can find more information in FB Graph API documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

And in the following stackoverflow thread: [Facebook API SDK revoke access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access)

And finally the following stackoverflow thread for an implementation using Koala gem (gem to control Facebook Graph API): [How to deauthorize User Facebook Permissions using Koala gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640242/how-to-deauthorize-user-facebook-permissions-using-koala-gem)