# How to deauthorize User Facebook Permissions using Koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I am using Koala to handle FB calls. Everything is working fine except I can't figure out how to deauthorize a user's FB permissions.

The equivalente REST call would be to:

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
```

The Koala wiki indicates all REST calls are supported via:

```
@rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)

@rest.fql_query(my_fql_query) # convenience method
@rest.fql_multiquery(fql_query_hash) # convenience method
@rest.rest_call("stream.publish", arguments_hash) # generic version
```

but this doesn't tell me much.

I would prefer to use Koala as I have app secret security enabled and generating app_secret_proof for plain FB REST calls is a major hassle. Koala handles it transparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.
After instantiating the `@rest` object:

```
@rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token, app_secret)
```

you can check out its methods via:

```
@rest.methods
```

and you'll notice it returns *RESTful* methods like `#get_object`, `#put object`, and our winner: `#delete_object`.
Then it's just a matter of doing:

```
@rest.delete_object("me/permissions")
```

success!

Comment: BTW you can even do `@graph.delete_object('me/permissions')` and not have to mess around with the @rest object