# How Can I allow the user to de-authorize my canvas app with the JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API SDK revoke access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access)

Can anyone provide a code snippet to de-authorize (or revoke the access token for) my canvas app with the JS SDK?

I've tried numerous things by following the links in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access), but the Documentation is confusing, and I keep recieving error messages.

**My current code:**

```
$('#deAuth_button').click( function(){
    var user_id = ____user_id____,
        ap_id = ____app_id____,
        req_id = ap_id + '_' + user_id;

     FB.api(req_id, 'delete', function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
       // error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
    });
});
```

**Relevant Links**:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#delete_requests
- [[SO] Facebook API SDK revoke access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sorted it out.  I was getting too complicated of course.  [The other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access) actually did have the answer, I was just applying it incorrectly at first.  I will also add my code snippet to that question.

**Working code:**

```
$('#deAuth_button').click( function(){
     FB.api('/me/permissions', 'delete', function(response) {
        console.log(response); // true
    });
});
```